# inserting in to database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a litte problem. I have this code, but this insert in to database only last input value. My function doing a new input, if u click + then coming again new input, but I want all these inputs values in to database, but this code inserting only last input value in to database.
Example: I inserting 53424345 and then 56546546, and only 56546546 goes in to database. But I want in to database 53424345, 56546546. Is that possible ? And how to do something like this ?

```
<table id="mytable">
        <tr id="number0" style="display:none;">
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('&nbsp;-&nbsp;',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to remove this number')); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid'); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trAdd"><td> <?php echo $this->Form->button('+',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to add another number','onclick'=>'addNumber()')); ?> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>



    <?php echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-2.1.1.min.js'));?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var lastRow=0;

    function addNumber() {
        lastRow++;
        $("#mytable tbody>tr#number0").clone(true).attr('id','lisanumbrid'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr#trAdd");
        $("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removeNumber('+lastRow+')');
        $("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('numbrid','data[Lisanumbrid]['+lastRow+'][lisanumbrid]').attr('id','numbridlisaNumber'+lastRow);
    }

    function removeNumber(x) {
        $("#lisanumbrid"+x).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Thanks, I accept all hints and solutions.

Comment: Does your input names has `[]` at the end? Like `lisanumbrid[]`

Comment: Like u see in code (above) , no .

Comment: Than your last input field variable is overwriting previous values.

Comment: I tried just add [] at the end, but this is not working, or I made something wrong. But this functions adding this "lastRow" at the end.

Comment: Show generated HTML output, as I see no modifications of name attribute

Comment: U dont see my code ? `<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid'); ?></td>` this is my input, and this adding in to database too.

Comment: do you want, I add onw picture in to question , then u see how this is look

Comment: I'm talking about `addNumber` function: cloning `#number0` row, changing it's id value, removing any style; Changing first input field `numbrid` attribute (whatever that means) to some `data[Lisanumbrid]...`, changing it's ID. But you never change newly created input field name to be `lisanumbrid[]`.

Comment: p.s numbrid = numbers, Okey and I need just add [] in to input ?

Comment: Yes, to be like `<input type="text" name="numbrid[]"/>`. Also show PHP update function

Comment: I dont have something like this, my input is different `<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid'); ?></td>`

Comment: When you echo that PHP function, you get that output...

Comment: Okey, but I dont see that, or .. ? Sorry Im newby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 changes, considering you are saving data into Model table:

1) Modify your input as

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid',array('name'=>'data[Model][0][lisanumbrid]')); ?>
```

2) Modify your addNumber() as

```
function addNumber() {
        lastRow++;
        $("#mytable tbody>tr#number0").clone(true).attr('id','lisanumbrid'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr#trAdd");
        $("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removeNumber('+lastRow+')');
        $("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('numbrid','data[Lisanumbrid]['+lastRow+'][lisanumbrid]').attr({'id':'numbridlisaNumber'+lastRow,'name': 'data[Model]['+ lastRow  +'][lisanumbrid]'});
}
```

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
File: C:\wamp\www\cakephp-2.5.6\app\View\Kontaktid\add.ctp
Line: 21

Comment: something is broken in `<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid',array('name'=>'data[Kontaktid][lisanumbrid][0]'))‌​; ?></td>`

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->input('lisanumbrid', array ('name'=>'data[Kontaktid][lisanumbrid][0]')) ?>

Comment: function addnumber not working now, if I click + then this doing nothing .

Comment: just replace the last line with 

$("#lisanumbrid"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('numbrid','data[Lisanumbrid]['+lastRow+'][lisanumbrid]').attr({'id':'numbridlisaNumber'+lastRow,'name': 'data[Model][lisanumbrid]['+ lastRow  +']'});

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65955/discussion-on-answer-by-naresh-walia-inserting-in-to-database).